# Coldfusion Builder & PhoneGAP

Tags: coldfusion

I am about to embark on using CF builder3 (windows 8.1) to develop a phonegap build for iOS.
My question is, do I need a MAC machine to do this?
I understand I need a signing key etc & although I have a developer account I hear that you may need a mac to build the keys. There are some products that do this for you without the need to buy a mac but I cant seem to find out if ColdFusion builder can.

Comment: i dont think you will be needing a mac to do this.

Comment: No you don't need a MAC but it is development advantage if you do.

Comment: How is it a 'development advantage' if he has a Mac?

Comment: If you decide later to do native iOS development you'll already be used to the OS.  I'm not sure if PhoneGap Build lets you get your app submitted to the App Store w/o using XCode to produce certs/keys and do the actual submission.  It's been a couple years since I did iOS development and Adobe may have made the process end-to-end not depend on having access to a Mac.